# How to customize login within SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have SugarCRM version 6.2 Community Edition with a custom module called Agents. Agents do not have User accounts. I want to allow Agents to log into the CRM instance. I understand to login we need User accounts. 
But is it possible to allow Agents to log in without creating a User? How?

Or is possible to relate a User to an Agent so that when the User logs in he/she can view that Agent's details?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just create a role for Agent and create users and assign to that Role . ( admin can create users and assign user to the Agent role)

At the end when you pull record from user table you can filter it based on role ( say agents) and use them in your custom module.

Anyway, For agents to login they will recieve auto-generated Email and password as and when admin creates them as Agents